# Return a list type from Product class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Product class in this file: **Libraries\Nop.Core\Domain\Catalog\Product.cs**

```cs
public partial class Product : BaseEntity
{
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    // 30 more fields, etc.
```

I have a method in a Controller here: **Admin\Controllers\ProductController.cs**

```cs
public ActionResult ExportExcelAll()
{
    // need to implement this:
    var products = new List<Product>();
    products = ???????

    byte[] bytes = null;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        _exportManager.ExportProductsToXlsx(stream, products);
        bytes = stream.ToArray();
    }

    return File(bytes, "text/xls", "products.xlsx");
    // PRODUCES AN EXCEL FILE
}
```

Using that Product class, I want write this query:

```
select Sku Price from product
```

But ... the results of the query MUST be returned in a `List<Product>` type:

```
var products = new List<Product>();
```

Can this be done by writing a method in the Product class or something?

Comment: Add `.ToList()` to the end of your query. In other words, `(from p in products select new { Sku = p.SKU, Price = p.Price }).ToList();`

Comment: thanks, but how do I write the query? I'm new to MVC and LINQ.

Comment: We have to know where the data is stored before we can define where it's going to come from ...e.g. if you're using a `Linq.dbml` you'd update the given query with the location of the data e.g., `var db = new LinqDataContext();` and add "db." to `(from p in **db.**products select new { Sku = p.SKU, Price = p.Price }).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MVC and Entity Framework and letting Visual Studio do all the scaffolding for you, you will have the following at the top of your controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
```

Then to query in your action:

```
var listOfProducts = (from p in db.Products
                     where p.Property == "condition"
                     select p).ToList();
```

If you are new to Linq I suggest downloading [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and running through the tutorials supplied. Additionally it is an invaluable tool when playing around with code!